# Looking for some clarification on Clojure syntax and functionality

Tags: syntax, clojure

What is the difference between this:

```
(keySet (map (keyword :number) queryResult)
```

and this:

```
(keySet (map #(get % "number") queryResult)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the `(keyword :number)` from your first example is redundant, because `keyword` converts its argument to a keyword, and `:number` is already a keyword. Which reduces your first example to:

```
(keySet (map :number queryResult))
```

When a keyword is used as a function, it returns the associated value for that key of the first argument or `nil` if it doesn't exist:

```
user=> (:number {:a "Hi" :number 23})
23
user=> (:number {:a "Hi" :ldsf 23})
nil
```

So the first example returns the result of applying `keySet` to the sequence of `:number` fields in `queryResult`.

Your second example, on the other hand, will apply `keySet` to the sequence of all `"number"` fields of `queryResult`.

Note that the the first example looks up the keyword `:number` while the second example looks up the string `"number"`.

And of course `:number` ≠ `"number"`:

```
user=> (= :number "number")
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one will look up the keyword `:number` in each item of queryResult, while the second will look up the string `"number"`. Which you want to use will depend on what type the keys in your map are.